# Stop application from launching if condition is not met

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

I need to show a message box and then stop my program if a condition is not met, how can I do so?

Right now I have this:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(condition == false){
        MessageBox.Show("Condition not met. Program will now close!");
        Application.Exit();
    }
    new window.ShowDialog();
}
```

but when I run it, the new window flashes very briefly and the program closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't show a new dialog, I just close the mainform out from under them if they are not authorized. This.Close immediately exits the program.

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some code here
    if (condition == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Condition not met. Program will now close!");
        //i log the user logged in
        this.Close();
    } 
    else 
    {
         //continue to setup the form
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are calling Application.Exit(); just after showing the dialog, without waiting to see what the dialogresult returns you. thats why its flashing and going away.

try this.

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Condition not met. Program will now close!", "Confirmation", messageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
if(result == DialogResult.Yes)
    //...
else if (result == DialogResult.No)
    //...
else
    //...
```

Comment: By dialog flashing, I mean the "new dialog.ShowDialog();". I should have worded that better.

Answer (score 1):

Use an else block:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(condition == false){
        MessageBox.Show("Condition not met. Program will now close!");
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else {
        new dialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

[Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not immediately exit the application.  It causes the message loop to end, but your code still finishes running the `MainForm_Load` method.

Comment: When I use an else statement, my form flashes briefly. How can I keep it hidden?

Comment: @user2705775 use elseif with specific condition

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to handle the Load event of your startup form because the startup form is already being shown at that stage.  You want to put the code in your Main method, which is where the startup form is created.  Here's what the Main method, in the Program.cs file, looks like by default:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

You simply wrap an 'if' statement around those three lines of code.  The Application.Run call blocks until the form it's passed closes, at which point the Main method completes and your app exits.  If you don't make that Application.Run call then the Main method completes immediately and the app closes without ever creating, never mind showing, a startup form.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: I don't think I will be able to do that since my condition relies on a COM port on the main form.

Comment: I never mess with the Program class, not that I cannot, just never had anything that I could not accomplish elsewhere.

Comment: @user2705775, in that case I would recommend moving the COM port out of the main form.  Put it in a class that you can access in the Main method and in the startup form.  Alternatively, create the startup form outside the 'if' block, check your COM port and then only call Application.Run inside the 'if' block.  You CAN do it this way IF you design your app such that you can do it this way.  Don't write some code and then assume that that code can't change if it stops you doing what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(condition == false){
        MessageBox.Show("Condition not met. Program will now close!");
        Environment.Exit(0);// or Application.Exit();

    } else {
    new dialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use an else statement, my form flashes briefly. How can I keep it hidden?